# Nginx cannot send whole response in a slow connection

Tags: linux, nginx, curl

Some user reported that cannot download whole response from my site when they are in a slow network connection.

I tested with `curl --limit-rate 1k`, and curl did report

```
 transfer closed with 769569 bytes remaining to read
```

Why is that, and how to solve this? I think it might relate to some nginx timeout config and googled a little bit, but cannot find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `sendfile`? Increase the amount of seconds of `send_timeout` until you find something ideal, something proportional to the largest file on your server. Here's an example

```
http {
  ...
  send_timeout 35s;
  ...
}
```

You also might want to read [the Cloudflare post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-curious-case-of-slow-downloads/) where they are describing your identical issue.

Hope this helps